# Placing hidden inputs in HTML forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following html for a table row and it is automatically echoed by a php file:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>' . $id . '</td>
            <td>' . $topic_num . '</td>
            <td>' . $topic . '</td>
            <td>' . $created_at . '</td>
            <td>
                <form class="input-group" action="tables/change_category_name.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="category"
                    class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Rename to...">
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" style="border: none;cursor: pointer;">submit</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

As each row contains a form to submit, I want to carry along the `$id` with the form when submitted. So that I can identify the `$id` in `change_category_name.php` to know which row in the database table to update. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden input to the form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">
```

and read it with `$_POST` variable

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `$id` from the `action` attribute as

```
<form class="input-group" action="tables/change_category_name.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Rename to...">
 <button type="submit" name="Submit" style="border: none;cursor: pointer;">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Output**

```
http://localhost:8012/test.php?id=1
```

And on the `change_category_name.php` you can read it as

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score -2):

you can change

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" style="border: none;cursor: pointer;">submit</button>
```

to

```
<button onClick="Submit()">submit</button>
```

then add a javascript to use ajax to send the request with any params you want.
hope it works for you!

Comment: Will the data in the input field be carried into `Submit()`?

Comment: I think you need to get input value by DOM operation.